# HTML/CSS - How can i line up my href pictures in a div?

Tags: html, css

I created a web page, i have need help with html/css to make a div for 6 pictures, 3 on top 3 below it - all are href. The pictures become very big and when i tried to resize them it put 4 pics on top and 2 on bottom.
Basic webpage with header, main section and div.
Here is what i have tried

```
<body>
    <div class="pagepicturecontainer">
        <h2>Test Gallery</h2>
        <div>
            <a href = "sectest1.html">
                <img class = "img1" src ="./img/bike1tl.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <a href = "sectest2.html">
                <img class = "img2" src ="./img/bike1tl.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <a href = "sectest3.html">
                <img class = "img3" src ="./img/bike1tl.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <a href = "sectest4.html">
                <img class = "img4" src ="./img/bike1tl.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <a href = "sectest5.html">
                <img class = "img5" src ="./img/bike1tl.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <a href = "sectest6.html">
                <img class = "img6" src ="./img/bike1tl.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would like some help with CSS and any improvement on my HTML.
This is my first time trying to make a full html/css website so please be kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more manageable to use CSS grid or any other library like bootstrap which simplifies the CSS grid.

```css
.image_box {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="pagepicturecontainer">
        <h2>Test Gallery</h2>
        <div>
            <div class="image_box" ><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2vs2Yi0pObR24br0K1Aj6MieJM1-lWOd7X9opMhIwf9yi9ie8"></div>
            <div class="image_box" ><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2vs2Yi0pObR24br0K1Aj6MieJM1-lWOd7X9opMhIwf9yi9ie8"></div>
            <div class="image_box" ><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2vs2Yi0pObR24br0K1Aj6MieJM1-lWOd7X9opMhIwf9yi9ie8"></div>
            <div class="image_box" ><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2vs2Yi0pObR24br0K1Aj6MieJM1-lWOd7X9opMhIwf9yi9ie8"></div>
            <div class="image_box" ><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2vs2Yi0pObR24br0K1Aj6MieJM1-lWOd7X9opMhIwf9yi9ie8"></div>
            <div class="image_box" ><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2vs2Yi0pObR24br0K1Aj6MieJM1-lWOd7X9opMhIwf9yi9ie8"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```